# How do I get a digital signature from a document using PHP

Tags: php, digital-signature

I am very new to this Digital Signature stuff.

- What I want to do, is check if a document is digitally signed.
- If it's signed, then verify the signature.

I have searched a lot. I found some helpful topics about verifying the signature (Using openssl), but I was unable to find anything about: Is the document signed or not
(I also found some related questions in stackoverflow, but not answered in a desired way)  I am not looking for any third party tools.

Are there any openssl methods or any other ways to know whether the document is signed or not signed using php?

**Edit**

Submitting documents are pdf, Do the type of documents makes ane difference in the process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start here:

[PHP OpenSSL Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php)

[openssl_verify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php)

For PDF files I would recommend [TCPDF](http://tcpdf.org)

Here is some signature related [example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_052.phps) (This is actualy for signin, not for verifying, but take a look and study)

Comment: Thanku rkosegi, Hmm looking into it.I want to know is it possibe or not get digital signature from document.My users will submit documents to me and i want to check is it digitally signed.

Comment: pdf documents, Sory i dont know how the user will sign,If this is a blunder please forgive me.Accroding to my belife user will have a digital signature certificate and he will sign the pdf documents using that and will submit it