# How do I check code signing in an uploaded file in PHP?

Tags: php, digital-certificate

Question 1: how do I check (in PHP) if an uploaded file is digitally signed? Just check "if", no matter of verifying the certificate expiring date or certificate chain

Question 2: how do I check what I was not interested in before, thus if the certificate is valid and not expired?

Context description: I develop some softwares and provide updates, personalizations and other stuff to my customers through a PHP website. Everything is (should be) signed using a code signing certificate by COMODO to ensure that browsers and antiviruses do not block my files.

I say "should be" because while main files are processed using structured procedures/tools, a number of very customized files are produced by diverse people in my company, not strictly connected to the developing team (they are just xml files packed up in an .exe file with InnoSetup).

I would like to set up a tool to ensure nobody can upload a file not digitally signed.

I'm afraid I've no clue where to start, not found anything enlightening on Google, so I do not have any code/efford to post.

Comment: This may be helpful yo you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494648/how-do-i-get-a-digital-signature-from-a-document-using-php

Comment: @jogesh_pi sorry for not answering, I was waiting to have the time to study the link and its links (and so recursevly on) a bit. That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot.